# Is there a way to stop firing the older code for New logic without modifying the old piece of code(Validation Rule, workflow, Triggers)?

Tags: org

We are using an org where multiple LOB is already running. 
We are implementing the new logic on top. but the earlier logic would still be fired for our new logic. Example, the Case object. Although, we have new record types for our new logic, The previous logic like the validation rule or the workflow rule & triggers will still be fired on our recordtype as they have not checked it.
Is there a way to stop firing the older code for our logic without modifying the old piece of code(Validation Rule, workflow, Triggers)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you uncheck the "Active" property on the validation rules, workflow rules, and triggers? Otherwise, there is no way to prevent the platform from executing these without modifying the logic itself.